# What type is repository pattern in?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, repository, repository-pattern

In general, I know that there are 3 big types of design pattern

1. Creational Pattern (Factory, Singleton, etc)
2. Structural Pattern (Composite, Adapter, Proxy, etc)
3. Behavioral Pattern (Specification, Command, etc)

But I dont know which type I can put the Repository pattern in.

**Is Repository pattern in one of three above type? Or is it kind of in the middle of (2) and (3) pattern?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Repository can be viewed as a special kind of Façade (structural) but also as a special kind of Factory (creational). Also, as the Repository often expose collection-like interface, then it might be a special application of Iterator (behavioral).

What I am trying to say is that neither those categories nor patterns themselves are any sort of definite doctrine. There are just some ideas and a language that tries to make them more explicitly visible. These categories are just helpers trying to express somehow what some patterns do. Also patterns are just various expressions of a generic loose coupling principles. Their borders are blurry.

Comment: I'm not sure about creational. A repository doesn't create any new object, does it ?

Comment: It creates a new *Object* based on persisted *Data*. Technically. But on higher level of abstraction you can consider this object is just brought back from the store, not created.

Comment: Rehydration is rarely performed by the Repository itself these days (mostly delegated to ORM). When you use a repo's `Get...()` method, you don't tell yourself "I want to construct a new object" or "X new objects" so calling it creational sounds a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 9):

A repository is a specialisation of the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) which is structural.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you refer to the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) by Martin Fowler.

He says:

> Repository: Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

He himself categorizes the pattern as "Object-Relational Metadata Mapping".

If you want to use the categories in the [GOF book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), I'd put it into the structural pattern category as the focus of this pattern is to present an interface/view to a client, similar to the Adapter/Facade/Proxy patterns.